# Finding limits in $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n > 3$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Lately I've been solving a few limits of the kind: $$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0)} f$$ and: $$ \lim_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0,z_0)} f$$

The best method I have found thus far is by converting from Cartersian coordinates to polar and spherical coordinates respectively and solve from there. I was wondering if there is a way to find limits in say, $\mathbb{R^6}$? That is how would i go about finding a limit of the kind: $$\lim_{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6) \rightarrow (a,b,c,d,e,f)} f \ ?$$

Comment: There are other coordinate systems in higher dimensions as well. An example is [hyperspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates)

Comment: Although I know that your question is not a joke, your notation (the limit having the same letter $f$ as the function $f$) reminded me of a joke problem once posed by my friend: Find $\Pi_{i=0}^{100}abc\ldots xyz$.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Expand the polynomial $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\cdots(x-y)(x-z)$.